# Color modifiers don't work in git aliases

Tags: bash, git, colors

I have my git alias

```
    lds = log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %ad%C(auto)%d\\ %C(reset)%s%C(blue)\\ [%an]" --date=short --decorate
```

(just shows oneline logs with proper formatting)

And I want to use color modifiers like `dim bold` etc. But when I add modifiers to color I'm getting weird error `fatal: option '--date=short' must come before non-option arguments`

I even tried to move options to the beginning of the alias:

```
    lds = log  --date=short --decorate --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h\\ %ad%C(auto)%d\\ %C(reset)%s%C(blue bold)\\ [%an]"
```

Error disappeared, but output now is empty. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found out that the reason is my quotes. I use `"` and that causes the error. If I write alias with single quotes `'` it will work perfectly. Also I needed to remove slashes from the alias.

```
lds = log --pretty=format:'%C(yellow)%h %ad%C(auto)%d %C(reset)%s%C(blue bold) [%an]' --date=short --decorate
```